# Splitting the array element at each index

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

How to split an integer element of an array of each index?

For example I have an array [145, 45, 15] so I want to convert it to [1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5]

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you wrote in an attempt to solve this?

Comment: What have you done so far? You are asking us to create a program for you, not to solve a problem. Make an attempt, and then we can help you if you run into issues.

Comment: basic idea for you - start to iterate over array elements and for every element - present it as a array of digits

Comment: @MikeElofson No , m not asking you to create the program , all i want to know about algo approach. I have no idea about what to do in this case so i cud not be able to attempt. All i want is Hint.

Comment: Converting each item to a string is probably a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not going to use anything other than an array (you could skip step one when using an arraylist since the size of that data structure is *dynamic*), you could:

1. loop over the array, counting all the digits and putting that in a counter.
2. make a new array with the size of the counter variable.
3. loop over the array again, then loop over the amount of digits (perhaps convert the digits to a string and then use the length() method) per element, adding all of these to your new array.

This is just a naïve solution I thought of in a minute. It's probably not the best, most performant way, but it's something to get you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Get all elements in a single string:

```
String allCharacters = "";

for(int n : yourIntArray)
{
    allCharacters += String.valueOf(n);
}
```

Create a new `String` array and fill it

```
String[] finalArray = new String[allCharacters.length];
for (int i = 0; i < allCharacters.length; i++)
{
     finalArray[i] = allCharacters.charAt(i);
}
```